# Number of ordered triples

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ordered triples of $(A, B, C)$ where

$A\cup B\cup C = \{1,2, .. 32\}$ and $A,\ B,\ C $ are disjoint

The answer is supposedly $3^{32}$ but I am unsure how to get this answer

Comment: Hint: For each of the $32$ elements, there will be a unique set among $A$, $B$ and $C$ which contains that element.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I'm not the OP, but would you mind expanding your comment?  I fail to see how it helps (I may be momentarily blind), but it doesn't seem to scale... i.e. if $A\cup B\cup C=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ with $A, B$, and $C$ disjoint, then we can't guarantee $3^{6}$ triples.  The number of triples should be $|A|\cdot|B|\cdot|C|$.  If each has two elements, then we only have $2^{3}$ triples, not $3^{6}$... or perhaps I misunderstand the question.  Similarly, in the OP's problem, if $|A|=|B|=11$ and $|C|=10$ there should be $11^2\cdot 10=1210$ tuples, not $3^{32}$.

Comment: Oh, perhaps I misunderstand.  I thought we were counting triples of the form $(a,b,c)$ where $a\in A$, $b\in B$, and $c\in C$.  This is more about counting "ordered partitions" of the set?

Comment: @TravisJ You are not fixing the sets. You are fixing the union of the sets and asking how many ways to split it into three labelled pieces. There is a nice bijection from such triples to "maps from $\{1,2,\dots,32\}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$", given by sending a triple to the map that assigns to an element the set (now labelled by $1$, $2$ or $3$) that it belongs to.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, thanks that makes sense.  I realized I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: easiest approach to me is to ask every element which set they belong  to :)